# Program to overlay text on an image gives endless string errors

Tags: c++, string, scope, char

I wrote a short program to overlay text on an image:

```
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void drawMM( const cv::Mat mm, std::string mCap ){
     //Input output windows
     cv::namedWindow( "Example2_5-out", cv::WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
     //Input window
     cv::imshow( "Example2_5-in", mm );
     //The Holder of Output(Copyright 2009 Holders Series)
     cv::Mat out = mm.clone();
     //Smoothing 
     cv::putText(out, mCap, cv::Point(40,200), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2.0, 255, 2);
     //Show the output image.
     cv::imshow( "Example2_5-out", out);
     //Wait.
     cv::waitKey( 0 );     

}

void inStr(int argc, char* argv[]){

     if (argc == 1)
     {
         string st = "If your boyfriend dosn't know what this is.";
         cout << st << endl;
     }else{
         string st = argv[1];
         cout << st << endl;
     }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string mT << inStr() << endl;
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    drawMM(img, mT);
    return 0;
}
```

but no matter what I do, every time I try to compile it I get two errors:

1. A unexpected token:

`CMG--00.cpp:39:15: error: expected initialiser before ‘<<’ token
     string mT << inStr() << endl;`

2. An undeclared scope:

`CMG--00.cpp:41:17: error: ‘mT’ was not declared in this scope
     drawMM(img, mT);`

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: inStr returns void, it should return string. Also you are not passing any variables to it

Comment: How do I format that?

Comment: fyi, C++ programs are not "scripts", those are something different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`string mT << inStr() << endl;`

There are a couple of things wrong with this line. First of all, you cannot use the `operator<<` here. If you want to create a variable, use `string mT = inStr();`

Also, your function `inStr`has two parameters: argc and argv, just like your main function does. You have to pass these parameters to the function. This results in `string mT = inStr(argc, argv);`

The next problem is your `inStr`function: Instead of returning the string, you are using `cout` which prints something in the console. You have to adjust your `inStr`: Replace `void`with `string` and use `return st;` instead of your current `cout`.

I would suggest reading another tutorial since you seem to lack some basic understanding of the language.